# How to install Android studio 3.0 beta 4 in windows?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have downloaded android studio 3.0 beta 4 for windows from the below mentioned link.

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html

The downloaded file was not exe file. Its zip file. I have extracted now. Then what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the `android-studio\bin\studio64.exe` you should follow this step by step instruction:

https://www.javaworld.com/article/3095406/android/android-studio-for-beginners-part-1-installation-and-setup.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the zip file
2. then run `android-studio\bin\studio.exe` or `android-studio\bin\studio64.exe`